# Scraping the Business name using Web class="search-item-header"

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the *Business Name* from a website.

I am receiving an error.
[image]e][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I26U.png)

On `For iCnt = 0 To .getElementsByTagName("h2").Length - 1`

I need to extract all the details available in the website like:

```
Business Name
Address
Telephone
Fax
Email
Website
```

in a sequence so all the details can be pasted into an Excel file.

```vb
Option Explicit

Const sSiteName = "https://www.thoroughexamination.org/postcode-search/nationwide?page=1"

Private Sub getHTMLContents()
    ' Create Internet Explorer object.
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False          ' Keep this hidden.
    
    IE.Navigate sSiteName
    
    ' Wait till IE is fully loaded.
    While IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
    Dim oHDoc As HTMLDocument     ' Create document object.
    Set oHDoc = IE.Document
    
    Dim oHEle As HTMLUListElement     ' Create HTML element (<ul>) object.
    Set oHEle = oHDoc.getElementById("search-item-header")   ' Get the element reference using its ID.
    
    Dim iCnt As Integer
    
    ' Loop through elements inside the <ul> element and find <h1>, which has the texts we want.
    With oHEle
        For iCnt = 0 To .getElementsByTagName("h2").Length - 1
            Debug.Print .getElementsByTagName("h2").Item(iCnt).getElementsByTagName("a").Item(0).innerHTML
        Next iCnt
    End With
    
    ' Clean up.
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set oHEle = Nothing
    Set oHDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

**No Response from 2nd Code:**

```vb
Sub TutorailsPoint()
Const URL = "https://www.thoroughexamination.org/postcode-search/nationwide?page=1"
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim topics As Object, posts As Object, topic As Object
Dim x As Long

x = 1

http.Open "GET", URL, False
http.send
html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("search-item-header")
For Each posts In topics
    For Each topic In posts.getElementsByTagName("h2")
        Cells(x, 1) = topic.innerText
        x = x + 1
    Next topic
Next posts
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with xhr if you use an UserAgent. Here is a code for all datasets per row with the present fields for all pages of your posted url.

```
Sub TutorailsPoint()
  Dim doc As Object
  Dim url As String
  Dim page As Long
  Dim hits As Long
  Dim maxPage As Long
  Dim maxPageKnown As Boolean
  Dim currRow As Long
  Dim nodeAllGroups As Object
  Dim nodeOneGroup As Object
  Dim nodeContactData As Object
  Dim nodeWebSite As Object
  Dim telephone As Boolean
  
  page = 1
  maxPage = 1
  currRow = 2
  Set doc = CreateObject("htmlFile")
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    'Call all pages
    Do
      url = "https://www.thoroughexamination.org/postcode-search/nationwide?page=" & page
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
      .send
      
      If .Status = 200 Then
        doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        
        'How many pages to call
        If Not maxPageKnown Then
          hits = CLng(doc.getElementsByClassName("summary")(0).getElementsByTagName("b")(1).innertext)
          maxPage = hits / 20
          If hits Mod 20 <> 0 Then
            maxPage = maxPage + 1
          End If
          maxPageKnown = True
          'Debug.Print maxPage
        End If
        
        Set nodeAllGroups = doc.getElementsByClassName("group")
        For Each nodeOneGroup In nodeAllGroups
          'Business name
          Cells(currRow, 1) = nodeOneGroup.getElementsByTagName("h2")(0).innertext
          'Address
          Cells(currRow, 2) = nodeOneGroup.getElementsByTagName("p")(0).innertext
          
          'Contact block
          Set nodeContactData = nodeOneGroup.getElementsByClassName("depot")
          If nodeContactData.Length <> 0 Then
            'Telephone
            If InStr(1, nodeContactData(0).innertext, "tel:") > 0 Then
              Cells(currRow, 3).NumberFormat = "@"
              Cells(currRow, 3) = Trim(nodeContactData(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innertext)
              telephone = True
            End If
            
            'Fax
            If InStr(1, nodeContactData(0).innertext, "fax:") > 0 Then
              Cells(currRow, 4).NumberFormat = "@"
              If telephone Then
                Cells(currRow, 4) = Trim(Replace(nodeContactData(0).getElementsByTagName("p")(0).FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NodeValue, "fax:", ""))
              Else
                Cells(currRow, 4) = Trim(Replace(nodeContactData(0).getElementsByTagName("p")(0).FirstChild.NodeValue, "fax:", "")) 'not sure, not seen no telephone
              End If
            End If
            
            'Email
            If InStr(1, nodeContactData(0).innertext, "email:") > 0 Then
              Cells(currRow, 5) = Trim(nodeContactData(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innertext)
            End If
            
            'website
            Set nodeWebSite = nodeContactData(0).getElementsByClassName("website")
            If nodeWebSite.Length > 0 Then
              Cells(currRow, 6) = Trim(nodeWebSite(0).innertext)
            End If
          End If
          
          telephone = False
          currRow = currRow + 1
        Next nodeOneGroup
        
        page = page + 1
      Else
        Cells(currRow, 1) = "Page not loaded. HTTP status " & .Status
        Cells(currRow, 2) = url
        currRow = currRow + 1
      End If
    Loop While page <= maxPage
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much i would appreciate if you can add more comments in the code so i can learn it. @Zwenn

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer was dropped by MS so it's not a good idea to use it. From now on, in VBA, my best option is to use Selenium (Selenium Type Library) to scrape the WWW. To get started with Selenium the right way you have to take care of the following:

1. Update the related .Net Framework
2. Install [Selenium Basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/download/v2.0.9.0/SeleniumBasic-2.0.9.0.exe) app
3. Download and install the version of [Chromedriver.exe](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) (see the latest version [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)) exactly compatible with the version of Google Chrome (which must be installed on the machine). Extract 'Chromedriver.exe' and put it at the same folder where Selenium Basic was installed (I've installed Selenium Basic here: 'C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic')
4. Add the reference in the VBE to the ActiveX library: 'Selenium Type Library'

Put the code in a standard module on the VBE:

```
Sub fnGetDataFromWWW()
    Dim oWD As WebDriver
    Dim post As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim groups As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim strText As String
    Dim intItem As Integer

    Set oWD = New Selenium.WebDriver
    oWD.Start "chrome"
    DoEvents
    oWD.Get "https://www.thoroughexamination.org/postcode-search/nationwide?page=1"
    DoEvents

    Set groups = oWD.FindElementsByClass("group")
    
    For Each post In groups
        strText = post.Attribute("outerText")
        For intItem = 0 To UBound(Split(strText, Chr(10)))
            If Trim(Split(strText, Chr(10))(intItem)) <> "" Then
                Debug.Print Split(strText, Chr(10))(intItem)
            End If
        Next
    Next post

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much i will try to learn the Selinium Basics as well. I would appreciate if you can share any site to learn it from scratch to advance.

Comment: Give it a try. You will have to learn by visiting various websites. Stack Overflow has some good material in its answers. The creator of Selenium Basic participates here with the codename FlorentBr (https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic)